# ¿Como extraer un nombre desde mi controller?

Tags: java, jsp, hibernate, maven, spring-tool-suite

Tengo ratos intentando extraer el usuario actual para poder hacer una comparación en mi controlador para que solo pueda eliminar una reservacion el usuario que la hizo.Pero no he encontrado la forma de obtener ese usuario, alguna idea?

*Controllador*

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/EliminarRESAU.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String borrarRESA(ModelMap model,@RequestParam("id") Long idRESA ) throws Exception {
    try {


        RESA resa = resaBo.obtener(idRESA);
        if (!resa.getEstado().equals("Activa")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"1"); 
            return "redirect:ListarRESAU.do"; 
        }
        if (resa.getEstado().equals("Activa")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,resa.getUsuario().getParticipante());
            return "redirect:ListarRESAU.do"; 
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"3"); 
        return "redirect:ListarRESAU.do";}

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

[image: Me gustaría extraer el nombre que aparece en la esquina superior izquierda]

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que usas Spring Security para el sistema de login, asi que podrias recuperar el usuario actual dentro del controlador con

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Si es que no lo tienes aun, puedes heredar de la clase `User` para poder agregar las propiedades que queramos, regularmente el `id` en la base de datos y el nombre del usuario

```
public class MiAppUser extends User  {
    private String nombre;
    private Long idUsuario;
    ....
```

Y en un Service que se encargue del login

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

   /*Buscamos el username y verificamos que exista*/

   MiAppUser user = new MiAppUser();
  //Setters de User
   user.setUsername(x);
   user.setPassword(x);
   user.setEnabled(x);
   user.setAccountNonExpired(x);
   user.setCredentialsNonExpired(x);
   user.setAccountNonLocked(x);
   user.setAuthorities(x);
   //Setters de MiAppUser
   user.setNombre(x);
   user.setIdUsuario(x);

   return user;
}
```

Y enconces en nuestro controllador usamos:

```
MiAppUser user = (MiAppUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

if(user.getIdUsuario() == idRESAUsuarioCrea){
     //podemos borrar
}
```